# ERROR: "Can request only one set of permissions at a time" en JAVA permission

Tags: java, android

Esto antes funcionaba, ahora , me presenta un error. Se me presenta el siguiente error "Can request only one set of permissions at a time"

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- Include following permission if you want to cache images on SD card -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" /> <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT    " />
```

En la clase public_reg2

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
};
    iv6 = findViewById(R.id.imageView6);


    iv6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                if (!hasPermissions(getApplicationContext(), PERMISSIONS)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(public_reg2.this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
                    iv6.performClick(); // EN ESTA LINEA ME MUESTRA EL ERROR
                } else {
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
            else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

ademas

```
   public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Soy aprendiz, cualquier aporte lo agradezco

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar tu archivo Manifest? ¿Podrías decirnos desde qué método estás llamando el código que hay en la pregunta? Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya pude encontrar el error. El problema está relacionado con la versión android TIMAMISU 33. Debo añadir permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGE en lugar de Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE tal como lo muestra en este enlace[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73826323/android-api-33-permissions-are-not-granted]

Comment: Creo que para mejorar tus prácticas, no deberías de llamar `iv6.performClick()` en el método que usas ahora, si no en `onRequestPermissionsResult()` deberías de allí preguntar si no te han dado permisos y allí llamar a `iv6.performClick()`

Comment: Excelente. Considera agregarlo como respuesta, por si puede servir a otros usuarios. Por otro lado, te recomendaría que manejes todos tus permisos desde el archivo Manifest, creo que así es más simple y más claro que hacerlo por medio de código Java. Para determinar qué permisos se otorgarán según la versión de Android de los usuarios, puedes usar `maxSdkVersion`, [ver la doc para más detalles al respecto](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element?hl=es-419).

Comment: Según [está respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035570/13419694) debes pedir todos los permisos una sola vez, no pedirlos permisos individualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Mi error se encontraba en que a partir de TIRAMISU se han modificado la forma de solicitar los permisos

En mi AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
```

Variables necesarias

```
 int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };
    int REQUEST_CODE = 200;
```

llamamos al metodo

```
iv6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        verificarPermisos(); 
    }
});
```

metodo

```
private void verificarPermisos() {

//para versiones posteriores a TIRAMISU
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        int PermisosExtSt = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES);

        if(PermisosExtSt == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            dialog.show();
        }else if  (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES)) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Es necesario que aceptes el permisos para seguir.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES}, REQUEST_CODE);

        }else{
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES}, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }else{

// en mi caso tengo usuarios que usan versiones inferiores a M. Si no es su caso, omita el siguiente if
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU ) {
            if (!hasPermissions(getApplicationContext(), PERMISSIONS)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(public_reg2.this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
                
            }else {
                dialog.show();
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}

//conservo este metodo para Versiones inferiores a TIRAMISU
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```